# Invalid application of 'sizeof' to incomplete type 'SDL_Window'

Tags: c++, struct, sdl, shared-ptr

Creating a pointer to an SDL_Window struct and assigning it to a shared_ptr, the mentioned error results.

Part of the class:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

class Application {
    static std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window> window;
}
```

Definition:

```
#include "Application.h"
std::shared_ptr<SDL_Window> Application::window{};

bool Application::init() {  
    SDL_Window *window_ = nullptr;
    if((window_ = SDL_CreateWindow(title.c_str(),
                                  SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                  SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                  window_width,
                                  window_height,
                                  NULL)
        ) == nullptr) {
        std::cerr << "creating window failed: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
    }

    window.reset(window_);
}
```

The error appears at 'window.reset()'. What is the reason and how to fix this behavior?

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but don't you have to deallocate via SDL_DestroyWindow instead of delete?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, `shared_ptr` will release the managed resource using `delete`. However, if you're using a resource that needs releasing another way, you'll need a custom deleter:

```
window.reset(window_, SDL_DestroyWindow);
```

<sub>NOTE: I'm fairly sure this will work, but I don't have an SDL installation to test it with.</sub>

Comment: @vmrob: Sorry, that was a typo, I meant the function `SDL_DestroyWindow`. The function pointer should be sufficient, without wrapping it up in a class.

Answer (score 8):

As said previously by [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18315430/1843978), you'll have to specify your deleter with `shared_ptr`. For a `unique_ptr`, however, you'll probably want to create a special type for your deleter so that it can be cleanly used as a template parameter. I used this struct:

```
struct SDLWindowDeleter {
    inline void operator()(SDL_Window* window) {
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    }
};
```

Then include the deleter via template parameter:

```
std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, SDLWindowDeleter> sdlWindowPtr = SDL_CreateWindow(...);
```

Comment: There's no need to wrap the function call in a class like that. The deleter can be any appropriately callable object, including a pointer to `SDL_DestroyWindow`.

Comment: If you use it with an `std::unique_ptr`, though, you'll need a type as opposed to a function pointer, correct?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that you'd digressed to `unique_ptr`. That can also take any suitably callable object, including a function pointer. It would be slightly messier, since you'd need to explicitly specify the deleter type when instantiating the template (i.e. `std::unique_ptr<SDL_Window, void(*)(SDL_Window*)>`), so a custom class type might be neater.

Comment: @MikeSeymour Really? I was actually unaware of that. Learning new things every day! Now that I'm looking at it though, it makes a lot of sense. I believe it's also recommended to use a custom type to eliminate the runtime overhead as the compiler can inline the function calls.